# Getting error : "invalid OS update specifier, comma expected" when running the assembler "as" on a mac

Tags: macos, assembly, clang

I'm using `clang` to compile to assembly language on a Macbook pro running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 with an Intel i7 core. However when I use `as` to produce object code I get an error from the line:
`.build_version macos, 10, 14    sdk_version 10, 14`
When I comment this line out from the generated `example.s` it works fine. Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it please? Is there a flag with clang to stop creating the problem line? I get the same issue if I use `gcc`.
Complete working example below

```
$ cat example.c
int main() {
    return 77;
}
$ clang -S example.c -o example.s
$ as -o example.o example.s
example2.s:2:31: error: invalid OS update specifier, comma expected
        .build_version macos, 10, 14    sdk_version 10, 14
                                        ^
$ cat example.s 
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 14    sdk_version 10, 14
    .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $77, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function

.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: Try to assemble through `clang` instead of `as`.  It is likely that there are slight differences in the syntax accepted by the two tools.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.